# How to program PUDE PUOV DDOE DDOV for ATmega328

Tags: atmega

I have been reading data sheet of ATmega328 on how to override the ports to alternate function in p90 Table 14-2. I keep seeing these names, but I cannot find how to write to them.

Thanks

Comment: please add a link to the datasheet into your question ... **do not** use a comment

Comment: My assumption here is you are viewing the block diagram and those labels are internal signals that you don’t have access to. Enabling an alternate function (usart, timer etc) automatically overrides the PORT and DDR settings.

Comment: Thanks jsotola for the reply. I cannot give the link as when I click it, it just download the datasheet in pdf file.

Comment: I want to confirm the enable INT1, I write 1 to EIMSK bit 1. Then write 1 to I-bit in SREG. Then this will OVERRIDE whatever written in PORTx, DDRx and PINx corresponding to the INT1 pin. That is over writing the general digital port control.

Comment: Right click on the link and then there should be an option to copy it.